# What is the strange dot that appeared next to the time when gone midnight?

Tags: gnome, time, date

It feels like I've asked this before so apologies if I have, I just can't find my previous post on this if there is one...

So anyway, last night when I was having some desktop-notifications and it had just gone midnight this dot appeared next to the date and time in the top bar (this has only ever happened once before a very long time ago):

[image]

Though when I clicked on the date and time it disappeared and I haven't seen it since, what does it mean and why did I get it?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That dot is meant to appear when you receive some sort of notification.

Notifications that trigger this dot are first shown as cards near the top of the screen. If you ignore a card, it'll eventually disappear and be moved to the notification area, which you can open by clicking on the date and time.

Once you open the notification area, your notifications are marked as read, and the dot will disappear.

From a chat conversation we had, you figured out that its seemingly inconsistent behavior is because of a bug in 15.10 that has been fixed in 16.04.